# XHTML correct syntax

Tags: xhtml

I am developing a card board which is 4x3. So I have tryed to do markup with XTHML Transitional. I have used  containers mixed with tables.
The example for first row:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <div class="slot_01"></div>
   <div class="slot_02"></div>
   <div class="slot_03"></div>
   <div class="slot_04"></div>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 ...
 </tr>
</table>
```

Is this correctly done? Or its better to use only div/span blocks instead everywhere and make styling through css?

Comment: One more thing, you don't have to start your questions with "I have a question." You obviously have a question because, well, you posted a question on Stack Overflow. Writing that just takes up precious space in the question previews on the question list pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a table, use `table`, `tr`, `td`, not `div`.

I think most people nowadays try to avoid tables for anything but "really tabular data" and prefer the "pure CSS" solution.

It depends a bit on your overall markup (e.g. what you want to display in the cells). In your case, I guess I would go for a tableless solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, You need td's in there, like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you really need to, put your divs inside the TDs.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is tabular in nature there's nothing wrong with using [tables](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/table/). Everyone else is correct - you need to use table cells instead of the divs in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally use div/span blocks if you can, but the above code is ok, you just need to wrap each div in a td element:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td><div class="slot_01"></div></td>
   <td><div class="slot_02"></div></td>
   <td><div class="slot_03"></div></td>
   <td><div class="slot_04"></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 ...
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you really don't need the div in here at all.  The class can go on the <td>.  Also consider using <thead> and <tbody>

Comment: i were going to use divs to have pictures inside of it which i will style out css :)

Comment: Viaceslav, are you actually using this table for tabular data, or just layout?  If it's just for layout then you shouldn't be using a table at all.

Comment: I am using it just for a layout for board and cards on it :)

Comment: tables should only be used for tabular data.  It is semantically incorrect to use tables for anything else.  The layout should be handled via CSS.  XHTML / HTML is just for content, not layout

Answer (score 0):

For the lay out of the entIre page I would do it tableless. Remember: XHTML is for structure, CSS for displaying the structure.